# Using hashchange or html5 history api for maintaining filter applied by the user on e commerce website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history, hashchange

I have hotel booking website with a search page with following filters:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl37B.png

I want to implement browser back functionality for filters here.

For example, a person visits website:
1) Applies filter for 5 star rating- the page reloads with all 5 star options.

2) Then the same user applies filter for Free Breakfast- the page reloads with all 5 star option having free breakfast.

I maintain the filter inputs in the url. So my url changes as follows:
1)User applying 5 star filter- url becomes /domain/?star=5

2)Same user applying Free breakfast filter- url becomes /domain/?star=5&fb=true

The issue comes when user clicks browser back, expecting to remove the filter for Free breakfast. The browser url changes to:
/domain/?star=5

But the results shown are still for 5 star with breakfast since it is picked by browser cache.

I want to hit api with the new query string whenever user clicks browser back/forward on this page.

I researched and have few options here:
1) Using html5 history api- new, rich in features but not compatible with all the browsers (pushing state of each filter and using pop state on browser back to hit api to bring new query string data)

2) Appending hash to the url whenever any filter is applied by the user- Now when user clicks browser back/fwd button, hashchange gets invoked and i would hit the api with the new query string.

Which approach is better. Is it possible to do it both ways? I feel that i am missing few cases which i can't think of now with the hash change approach.

It would be great if someone with good expertise can help me choose one.

Comment: you don't need either one if you refresh the page anyway...

Comment: There are multiple problems in that. First how do i detect browser back without using hashchange or popState event. Second and major one is why would i reload page with so many other contents i.e. cities drop down and other filter drop downs and not hit api to just change the listings or part of page data?